# clearTimeout is not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what is wrong with my code here, I've set the variable global but the clear timeout is still not working here.

Thank you,
Kelvin

```
var myslide = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = null;

    $('ul#panel li a').click(function () {
        stopAuto();
        $('ul#panel li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        current = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#wrapperSlide').clearQueue();
        $('#wrapperSlide').scrollTo($(current), 800);
        return false;
    });

    if (current==null)
    { 
        $("ul#panel li").each(function(i){
        var counter1 = i+1;
        var timer1 = counter1 * 5000;
        myslide = setTimeout(function(){
        setLoop1(counter1);
        },timer1);
    });
    } else {
        $('#wrapperSlide').clearQueue();
        return false;
    }
});
```

these are the functions for looping the slide images and stop auto

```
  function setLoop1(counter)
{     
      var counter4 = counter;
      var myID = $('a#'+counter4).attr('href');
      $('ul#panel li a').removeClass('active');
      $('a#'+counter4).addClass('active');
      $('#wrapperSlide').scrollTo($(myID), 800);
}

//function to stop the auto slide

function stopAuto() {

    clearTimeout(myslide);
}
```

Comment: What makes you sure that `stopAuto()` is being called?

Comment: whenever the "ul#panel li a" is clicked, the stopauto() is executed; however it didn't clear the timeout

Comment: Are you **sure** the function is being called? Have you put `console.log()` statements in it, or used the debugger?  When you do that, also check the values of the "myactive" and "myslide" variables (they should be integers) and also add logging when you set them up in the first place, and make sure the numbers are the same.

Comment: yes, i did. The myactive and myslide values are integers (about 21000). but it didn't get cleared.

Comment: FYI: there's no need to qualify "id" lookups ("#foo") with the element type; it just slows things down.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting those two timers for **each separate `<li>` element**:

```
    $("ul#panel li").each(function (i) {
        var counter1 = i + 1;
        var myID = $('a#' + counter1).attr('href');
        setLoop1(counter1, myID);
    });
```

However, that `setLoop1()` function uses the same two variables.  Each timer is **distinct** from the others, and the return value from `setTimeout()` is a distinct value each time you call it.  You can't store a bunch of different numbers in a single simple variable.

What you should be doing is storing the timer in a jQuery "data" property on each `<li>` element. Then your "click" handler can cancel the timeout from that. Or, perhaps you don't need a separate pair of timer functions for each list item.

Comment: I have updated my code to only create one timer, however the clear timeout is still not working

Comment: @kelvin19 you only **set** that "current" variable inside the "click" handler. It will always be `null`, therefore, at that `if` statement, and you're **still** creating the timer **inside** the `.each()` iteration over the `<li>` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am finally able to clear the timeouts. Yes, I do have to clear all the timeouts that's been created. It stops the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases are here possible as I see, either the **stopAuto()** function is not being called or if its is being called, the **stopAuto()** function is undefined when it is called. So I would suggest to define the **stopAuto()** function before it is being called and use some debugger tool to see the console.

Comment: I've checked that the stopAuto() is called, but the clearTimeout never clears the timeout.

Comment: Did you console something inside stopAuto?

Comment: The problem is that he's setting up **multiple** timers, one for each `<li>` in a list. Thus those two variables just contain the timer ID for the last one.

Comment: When the stopAuto is called the myactive and myslide variables are null as initialized and these variables are assigned correct values after the stopAuto function call. So I think these variables should be provided their valus first befor calling clearTimeout.

Comment: the stopAuto() is only executed after user has clicked on the pagination a link. So the value of myactive and myslide exist already.

Comment: @Pointy: Now I see your point, myslide is a single variable and he is assigning a new value for each of the li elements to it, so only the timer with the latest value is being cleared.
So its better to use the data property as you mentioned ore store all these values in an array and clear them all. But the second option is really horrible.